# gcloud app deploy '--appyaml' flag doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

For Google App Engine, I want to inject `env_variables` into my `app.yaml` upon deploy. In the docs for `gcloud app deploy`, I see that there is the flag `--appyaml` that will:

> Deploy with a specific app.yaml that will replace the one defined in the DEPLOYABLE.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

So I have a Fabric script that reads my `app.yaml`, injects my extra env variables, writes this new app.yaml to a tempfile, and then runs `gcloud app deploy`. The command to `gcloud` ends up looking like this:

`gcloud app deploy . --version dev --project myproject --appyaml='/var/folders/1z/qk45g9p934lg75byl8b74xyh0000gn/T/tmpgdjVUG.yaml'`

The deploy succeeds and new code gets uploaded, however my new env variables don't seem to make it up.

If I provide a bogus value to `--appyaml` then it throws an error, so it does seem to use my input.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you intervene, manually copy the YAML file from `/var/folders...` into the project directory and try deploying without the `--appyaml` flag? This will confirm whether the YAML that is being generated works correctly. If that works, then the issue is in resolving the `--appyaml` flag.

Comment: Yes, doing it that way works, and my env variables make it through

Comment: Good. OK. Next please keep the file in the app directory but rename it and reapply the `--appyaml` flag using the in directory reference. It may be that the deployment is unable to pull YAML files from outside the deployment context.

Comment: i called it `newapp.yaml` put it at the project root and ran the command `gcloud app deploy . --version dev --project myproject --appyaml='newapp.yaml'` and it didnt work. I then tried again, but i removed the original `app.yaml` from the folder and `gcloud app deploy` just hung

Comment: Just point your GAE descriptor without `--appyaml` flag, e.g.: `gcloud app deploy newapp.yaml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested it on standard AppEngine with small `HelloWorld` modification in node.JS like this:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var my_respond = "variables: ";
    res.status(200).send(Object.entries(process.env)).end();
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The sample is showing environment variables as result.

Than I added simplest `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: nodejs10
env_variables:
  MY_VAR: "my value from app.yaml"
```

Than in other location I have added different `yaml` called `app1.yaml`:

```
runtime: nodejs12
env_variables:
  MY_VAR: "my value from app1.yaml"
```

So this is changing node version and value of `MY_VAR`.

According to my tests this seems to be working little bit differently than explained in the doc, at least I understand it differently.

It's possible to use `--appyaml` flag, but only when there is no `app.yaml` file in the directory. If you do not have it in app directory, than using the flag you can point to different `yaml`.

So when I was trying to deploy with `gcloud app deploy --appyaml="/home/vitooh/app1.yaml"` and `app.yaml` was in application directory, the app was deployed with it - so the flag does not do anything. However when I done it without `app.yaml` the flag works, variable value is changed.

Actually you can spot it just after submitting command where there is a summary shown, just before you confirm deployment, in `descriptor` value like this:

```
descriptor:      [/home/vitooh/app1.yaml]
source:          [/home/vitooh/appEngine/nodejs-docs-samples/appengine/hello-world/standard]
target project:  [xxxxx-test-01]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20200819t094956]
target url:      [https://xxxxx-test-01.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?
```

Comment: I tried removing my `app.yaml` from my directory, but when i do the `gcloud app deplpy` command hangs. But, that's good to see that the `descriptor` is supposed to update to the value supplied to `--appyaml`, I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: OH! it wasn't hanging, it just takes a really long time (almost a minute) before it prints the `Services to deploy:` output. It looks like it works with the tempfile too. I got my descriptor field to update. That's a bummer that I have to remove the `app.yaml` though. I almost rather just make a `.tempapp.yaml` file in the project directory and use that as my deployable instead of using the `--appyaml` flag. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The question is a blackbox without any details: "I have a fabfile and then things happen but they happen wrong". However here's a tip how to do this a bit simpler without messing with `app.yaml`. `app.yaml` can contain a directive called `includes`, which can reference another yaml file, where you can have the environment variables, so you dont have to touch the original file.

app.yaml:

```
(...)

includes:
  - my_vars.yaml
```

my_vars.yaml:

```
env_variables:
    MY_VAR: value
```

Comment: Hmm, the other poster answered the question of what went wrong with the `--appyaml` flag, but I may actually end up doing something like this instead. Thanks!