# Unable to provide custom app.yaml file for Java GCP App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, gcloud

I have a Java 11 GCP App Engine project and I'm trying to use different `app.yaml` files depending on the environment (e.g., `app-dev.yaml`, `app-prod.yaml`, etc). The `yaml` files in the `/appengine` directory like `src/main/appengine/app-dev.yaml` and so on.

There is an [SO post about this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476841/gcloud-app-deploy-appyaml-flag-doesnt-seem-to-work), but the answer doesn't work because it clobbers the `descriptor` which in Java should be the `pom.xml` (see my **Approach 2** for more information).

**Approach #1**

*UPDATE: Solved! In order to use this approach you must be on gcloud 298.0.0+*

First, I tried using the `--appyaml=APPYAML` argument found in https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--appyaml:

```
gcloud app deploy [DEPLOYABLES …] [--appyaml=APPYAML] [--bucket=BUCKET] ...
```

I ran the following and received an error that the `appyaml` argument isn't recognized.

```
$ gcloud --project=my-project app deploy --appyaml=app-dev.yaml
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) unrecognized arguments: --appyaml=app-dev.yaml
```

The fully qualified path to `app-dev.yaml` doesn't work either.

**Approach #2**

Next I found a slighly different syntax in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml that looks like this:

```
gcloud app deploy service-name-app.yaml
```

I tried the same locally but pointed to my custom `app-dev.yaml` like so, but it breaks:

```
$ gcloud --project=my-project app deploy src/main/appengine/app-dev.yaml
...
descriptor:      [/Users/SomeDev/IdeaProjects/my-project/app-server/src/main/appengine/app-dev.yaml]
source:          [/Users/SomeDev/IdeaProjects/my-project/app-server/src/main/appengine]
target project:  [my-project]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20200831abcdefg]
target url:      [https://my-project.uc.r.appspot.com]
```

This breaks because it thinks the `app-dev.yaml` is the `descriptor` file instead of a `pom.xml`, so it errors out with the following:

```
Error message: did not find any jar files with a Main-Class manifest entry
```

To compare, I ran a normal deployment without a custom `yaml` file and you can see the `pom.xml` is the value of the `descriptor`.

```
$ gcloud --project=my-project app deploy
...
descriptor:      [/Users/SomeDev/IdeaProjects/my-project/app-server/pom.xml]
source:          [/Users/SomeDev/IdeaProjects/my-project/app-server]
target project:  [my-project]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20200831abcdefg]
target url:      [https://my-project.uc.r.appspot.com]
```

Is there a recommended way to make this work, or is this the wrong approach entirely?

Comment: Are you able to deploy your app without complex app-ENV.yaml file logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your "Approach #1" you have to upgrade your gcloud to version >= [298.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#app_engine_4) here  --appyaml parameter have been added - quite recently in Jun'20.

Looking at your "Approach #2". If you are running `gcloud app deploy` (without parameters) it search for descriptor `app.yaml` in current directory and if not found - than for `pom.xml`. If you want to use `pom.xml` from different localization you have to remove it from current directory. I didn't test it to the very end, just tested the descriptor value in summary.

Anyway I don't think using above is best way to do it. When you use `pom.xml` as descriptor it means that you are using feature called "[deploy your Maven project as source code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#deploy_maven_source_projects_to_the_java_11_runtime)". Which is not main way to deploy app engine with maven.

According to my understanding if maven was used for build, its possible to use the jar in `entrypoint` of `app.yaml` file ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#application_startup)) or maven goal `appengine:deploy` ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/using-maven) + [article that should be interesting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/testing-and-deploying-your-app)).

Comment: I want to confirm it was the the version problem. I was on `297.0.0`, just barely missing the right version by a few days! Running `gcloud components update` fixed everything and now `--appyaml` works. Thanks for catching that little nuance.